# Why would I use !! in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

While reading lodash source code, I saw:

```
this.__chain__ = !!chainAll;
```

Why would one use `!!` on the `chainAll` parameter?

I assume this is a safer way to detect falsy values or dealing w/ different JavaScript versions, but would like to know the scenario it protects.

Comment: It converts a value to its boolean counterpart.  Now you *know* that it's a boolean instead of it being a string or something else.

Comment: Easy to search for btw: [`[javascript] "!!"`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%22%21%21%22).

Comment: I searched for [javascript] !! and found nothing.  #fail

Answer (score 4):

The `!!` construct is a simple way of turning any `JavaScript` expression into
its `Boolean` equivalent. For exmaple: `!!"something" === true`, while `!!0 === false`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sC6Yj/)

Answer (score 0):

JS use dynamic type for variable. Thanks to this trick you convert the variable into a boolean if it was not a boolean, an it doesn't modify the value if it was a boolean